# Manupilating a dataframe with a pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

I want to create a piped version of the code below with the `%>%` operator.

```
main_details <- select(houses, PID, Lot.Area, Bldg.Type:Year.Built,
  Mo.Sold, Yr.Sold, SalePrice)
expensive_houses <- filter(main_details, SalePrice > 150000)
ages_added <- mutate(expensive_houses, OLD_HOUSE = Year.Built < 1960)
```

I tried the following:

```
main_details <- select(houses, PID, Lot.Area, Bldg.Type:Year.Built,
  Mo.Sold, Yr.Sold, SalePrice) %>%
expensive_houses <- filter(SalePrice > 150000) %>%
ages_added <- mutate(OLD_HOUSE = Year.Built < 1960)
```

However, this does give me an error.. Can someone explain me where I need to place the %>% operator in my code to make a piped version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefit of using pipe is you don't have to create such intermediate objects. Left hand side of pipe is the first argument to the function at right hand side. So you can use:

```
library(dplyr)

houses %>%
  select(PID, Lot.Area, Bldg.Type:Year.Built, Mo.Sold, Yr.Sold, SalePrice) %>%
  filter(SalePrice > 150000) %>%
  mutate(OLD_HOUSE = Year.Built < 1960)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So, we extract houses from select because we use the %>% ?

Comment: @Melissa Yes. So if you see `?select` the first argument is `.data` which comes from LHS i.e `houses`, similarly for `?filter` has first argument as `.data` which is the output from LHS above it i.e output from `seelct`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(houses)[SalePrice > 15000, .(PID, Lot.Area, Bldg.Type, 
     Year.Built, Mo.Sold, Yr.Sold, SalePrice)][, OLD_HOUSE := Year.Built < 1960][]
```